# Save the file with the name of the site

Tags: java, file-io, web-scraping

The following code saves the page's content to a file:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;



public class url
{
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
           try
                  {
                    URL PageUrl;
                    URLConnection GetConn = null;
                    GetConn = null;

                     PageUrl = new URL("https://www.google.ru/");
                     GetConn = PageUrl.openConnection();

                    GetConn.connect();

                    InputStreamReader ReadIn = new InputStreamReader(GetConn.getInputStream());
                    BufferedReader BufData = new BufferedReader(ReadIn);
                    String htmlFileName = ("C:\\hello.html");
                    FileWriter FWriter = new FileWriter(htmlFileName);
                    BufferedWriter BWriter = new BufferedWriter(FWriter);
                    String UrlData = null;
                    while ((UrlData = BufData.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                          BWriter.write(UrlData);
                          BWriter.newLine();
                    }
                    BWriter.close();
              }
              catch(IOException io)
              {
                   System.out.println(io);
              }
      }
}
```

But I need the file have the same name as the page of the website, for example, it has to somehow get the name of the web page and assign it as the file's name.

Comment: I'm still new, and still do not understand this, you can write the code, I'm sure it's easy for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [URL.getFile()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#getFile%28%29) to get the filename. I.e

```
...
String htmlFileName = PageURL.getFile();
...
```

Note that different URLs may refer to the same file: `http://example.com/test.html#anch1`, `http://example.com/test.html`, `http://example.com/test.html?a=b` - all three refer to the same `test.html` file here. In this case you might want to combine `getFile()`, `getRef()` and `getQuery()` somehow.

It is worth to mention some issues in your code:

1. start variable names with `lowerCase` instead of `UpperCase`;
2. Close resources in `finally` blocks. Better, if you use Java 7, use [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Comment: thank you very much and can insert, what advice do you have in my code

Comment: I think the text *"`lowerCase` instead of `UpperCase`"* should have the code-blocks removed (since the words ain't code), and instead point to a [direct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java) or [indirect](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html), [general](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html) or [specific](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367) Java code conventions doc.